# For loop to store results of confusion matrix

Tags: r, loops, predict, confusion-matrix

I'm attempting to store the results of a confusion matrix within a for loop. Right now the loop just prints the results of the analysis for each iteration.

```
for(i in 1:50){
train.cpg.t2 <- sample(nrow(cpg.updated.2), 2/3 * nrow(cpg.updated.2))
cpg.train.t2 <- cpg.updated.2[train.cpg.t2, ]
cpg.test.t2 <- cpg.updated.2[-train.cpg.t2, ]

model.nb2 <- naiveBayes(group ~ ., data = cpg.train.t2)
naive.cpg2<-predict(model.nb2, cpg.test.t2)
myconf<-confusionMatrix(predict(model.nb2, cpg.test.t2), cpg.test.t2$group)

print(myconf)



}
```

Rather than simply printing `myconf` I would like store the results of the `predict` function and then implement the `confusionMatrix` function all 50 iterations of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of improving this question but what I think you're trying to do is use `replicate`.

```
f <- function(cpg.updated.2) {
train.cpg.t2 <- sample(nrow(cpg.updated.2), 2/3 * nrow(cpg.updated.2))
cpg.train.t2 <- cpg.updated.2[train.cpg.t2, ]
cpg.test.t2 <- cpg.updated.2[-train.cpg.t2, ]

model.nb2 <- naiveBayes(group ~ ., data = cpg.train.t2)
naive.cpg2<-predict(model.nb2, cpg.test.t2)
myconf<-confusionMatrix(predict(model.nb2, cpg.test.t2), cpg.test.t2$group)
myconf
}

results <- replicate(n = 50, expr = f(cpg.updated.2))
```

A word of advice. You'll get much better quality answers if you improve the question a bit. For starters `confusionMatrix` is not in any of the packages that I'm familiar with therefore it's impossible to run your code without installing extra packages, which is not great. However, your question is about storing output of a loop so the question can be simplified significantly and does not need `confusionMatrix` at all.